# how to run a for loop over numbers stored as a numpy array in a list in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, for-loop

I have a for loop which in the simplest case has two iterations. Number of iterations are fixed. Then I want to for example print the numbers stored as arrays in a list. This is my list:

```
data = [np.array([450., 451., 452., 445.]),
        np.array([10., 20., 30.])
```

My list has two arrays and I want to print each array in an iteration. I tried:

```
for i in range(2): # the number of iterations is fixed beforehand
    for j in range(len(data[i]) - 1):
        print(data[j], data[j + 1])
```

I wrote the first for loop simply by `for i in range (2)` but in reality iterations are coming automatically and I do not define them, but the numbers of arrays stored in my list exactly matches the number of iteration.

In my first iteration, I want to print pairs of numbers stored in the first array:

```
450., 451.
451., 452.
452., 445.
```

And in the second iteration I want to print numbers stored in the second array:

```
10., 20.
20., 30.
```

Comment: If it is `i` in `range(2)` what is `data[j]` supposed to be when `j > 1`? Use something like `data[i][j]`, although using indices at all isn't needed for something like this. You can iterate over lists and arrays directly.

Comment: Dear @John Coleman, I want to print firstly numbers in the first array of data and then the second array. I thought maybe this is the way to do that.

Comment: @John Coleman, in each array I start printing from the first to the next one. For example 10 and the next one which is 20. and 20 with its next one which is 30. In first array also 451 and 452 are repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need fixed iterations. The outer loop should be

```
for arr in data:
```

Probably the simplest way to iterate over the array like you want is

```
    for i in range(len(arr) - 1):
        print(arr[i:i+2])
```

Notice that in your original loop you were printing `data[j]` and `data[j + 1]` instead of `data[i][j]` and `data[i][j + 1]`. My recommendation is to iterate directly over the list instead of using indices, so `arr` replaces `data[i]`.

You can cheat and create a view that's exactly the elements you want for your array instead of looping:

```
    view = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr, shape=(arr.size - 1, 2), strides=arr.strides * 2)
    print(view)
```

Comment: Dear @Mad Physicist, I do appreciate your solution. But, the point is that I am not creating the first loop. I have a big script and it runs several iterations. In the middle of the script and in first iteration I am crearing the list. Then, I need to use each array in the correct loop. For example, the first one in the first loop, the second array in the second loop and so on. The solution you provided is not doing exactly what I expected. Sorry for my unclear post.

Comment: @Ali_d. I think my update should fix that. Use `data[i][j]` instead of `data[j]`. Also, I had a typo I just fixed.

Comment: @Mad Physicist, sorry for taking your time but I only see the following when I run your code: `[450.]
[451.]
[452.]
[10.]
[20.]
[30.]`

Comment: @Ali_d. For catch. Another typo. Fixed `i+1`->`i+2`

Comment: @Mad Physicist, thanks for devoting time ti my issue but still I have the problem of iteration. At the moment each row is printed as a iteration but I want the first three rows in the first iterationa dn last two ones in another one. The problem is that this aray is created just in the first iteration but I need to use it#s arrays later.

Comment: @Ali_d. I don't know what that means. Sounds like you might need to ask another question.

Comment: @Mad Physicist, I mean first three printed rows will be printed or used in the first iteration and the last two ones will be used for the iteration. The problem is that I have no control on iterations and just I should adjust arrays to be printed in the correct iteration